# Undefined reference error while compiling a simple mutlifile class program

Tags: c++

This is my main file:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "practice.h"

int main()
{
    practice obj(2);
    obj.whatever();
}
```

This is my .h file:

```
#include "practice.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

practice::practice(int num)
{
    h=num;
}
void practice::whatever()
{
    cout<<h;
}
```

This is my cpp file:

```
class practice
{
public:
    practice(int);
    void whatever();

private:
    int h;
};
```

I  cant seem to figure this out. Whenever i try to combine, it shows an error saying undefined refernce to `practice::practice(int)`, undefined reference to `practice::whatever()` and ld returned to 1 exit status

Comment: @johand. `It looks OK` Really?

Comment: @DimChtz: wow... I totally missed the cpp/h swap... Focused on bad link... Shame on me.

Comment: How do you compile your code?

Comment: oh... I did switch it in the question by mistake. Sorry. Haven't been able to find the solution yet

Comment: @mike if you are asking me which compiler I use, it's Code blocks

Comment: Then my crystal ball says you forgot to add the second .cpp file to the project.

Comment: wow I am so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have your cpp and header files backwards... You should be creating the class, and defining the layout in your header, and then in your cpp file you should have the details.

Comment: I think he just switched it in the question, because he includes the header in the ".h file"

Comment: yeah sorry my mistake.